# How to refactor for loop, which calls a function with multiple arguments, to `*apply`?

Tags: r

Please help me in simplifying the below for loop into an `*apply` function. I want to avoid the explicit `for loop`, but am unable to figure out 
where to put the extra arguments. The below code works absolutely fine, but I am interested in improving it.

`rankall` is my function name, `state` is a vector, `hospital` is a vector.

```
rankall <- function(outcome, num = "best") {

  df.outcome <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character")
  state <- unique(df.outcome[,7])
  size <- length(state)
  hospital <- character(size)

  for(i in 1:size) {

    hospital[i] <- rankhospital(state[i], outcome, num)

  }

  df <- data.frame(hospital,state)
  df[order(df[,2]),]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the below line instead of the `for loop`

```
hospital <- sapply(state, rankhospital, outcome = outcome, num = num)
```

instead

```
for(i in 1:size) {

    hospital[i] <- rankhospital(state[i], outcome, num)

  }
```

When you have multiple arguments, use the first argument as usual but the remaining arguments as additional arguments to `sapply` function.